# Automapper - how to create map for this specific value object?

Tags: c#, entity, domain-driven-design, automapper, object-object-mapping

This is a representation of my  domain model:

```
public class AddressInfo
    {
        private readonly string addressee;
        private readonly string company;
        private readonly string city;



        public string Addressee
        {
            get { return addressee; }
        }

        public string Company
        {
            get { return company; }
        }

        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
        }
    }



 public class Address
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public AddressInfo AddressInfo { get; set; }
        }
```

This is my entity class:

```
public class AddressEntity
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressInfo AddressInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This is the representation of my repository where I am able to retrieve the values but not map them in the way I want to.

```
 public class AddressRepository
    {
      public static void CreateMappings()
        {
         //How to construct a map here to take care of 
         //the map creation of AddressInfo??

         Mapper.CreateMap<AddressEntity, Address>();
        }

      public IEnumerable<Address> GetAllAddresses (User user)
        {
            var addressentities = GetAddresses(user.Id);
            return addressentities == null? 
                                 null: 
                                 Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Address>>(addressentities);
        }


    }
```

**How to create the map so that AddressInfo is taken care of ????**
Currently it is not populated with the retrieved values as it is obviously not mapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `AddressInfo` class doesn't have setters or constructors parameters who then go set to your addressee, company, city backing variables. So there is no way for `AutoMapper` to set the data.

If you wanted to control how `AutoMapper` maps you can create a class that inherits from `TypeConverter`.

```
//This is also easier to unit test if you have conversions that are not 100% automappable.
public class AddressEntityToAddress : TypeConverter<AddressEntity, Address>
{
    protected override Address ConvertCore(AddressEntity source)
    {
        if(source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var destination = new Address
        {
            Id = source.Id,
            DisplayName = source.DisplayName,
            AddressInfo = source.AddressInfo
        };  

            //do other magic you may want during conversion time

        return destination;
    }
}
```

After you create the type converter class you can set AutoMapper to use it like this in your CreateMapping method:

```
public static void CreateMappings()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<AddressEntity, Address>().ConvertUsing<AddressEntityToAddress>();
}
```